# NoSuchMethodError the method was called on Null

Tags: flutter, dart

in this code below WeatherModel tried to get current location of android phone,
my problem here is once I start runing it show NoSuchMethod Found, and it says reciever is null,
as I tried a lot of debugging just to see where is my problem.
I now understand that my problem is when I create instance of Location() in WeatherModel, longitude and latitude are null, it never gets value and I dont know why...

Sorry for my bad english :(

```
const apiKey = 'e3653190f2b1d4803287b3074ecfe618';
const apiWeatherURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

class WeatherModel {

  Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async {

    Location location = Location();

    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey');
    var weatherData = networkHelper.getData();
    return weatherData;
  }

  }
.....

class Location {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      Position _position = await Geolocator()
          .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      longitude = _position.longitude;
      print(longitude);
      latitude = _position.latitude;
      print(latitude);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
.........

class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.url);
  final url;

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(" Sarkawtua $data");
      return data;
    } else
      print("Error ${response.statusCode} keshay Internet");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you instance fields are not updated, so they are null. You have method for getting current location but it's not fired in `getLocationWeather`.

```
Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async {

    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey');
    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return weatherData;
  }
```

Edit: You also must await `networkHelper.getData()` method to get not Future Object.